# Access violation in module 'DBXCommondriver220.dpl'

Tags: banco-de-dados, c++, firebird, embarcadero

Estou com problema ao usar Firebird no Embarcadero C++ XE8.

Erro: `Access violation in module 'DBXCommondriver220.dpl'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minha solução:

Reinstalar o firebird x32, mesmo windows sendo x64, com a opção da imagem abaixo selecionada:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]